# Spring : Sharing Application Context between different servlets

Tags: spring, soap

I have a web application and SOAP Web service in same project. I have defined two servlet xml

mvc-servlet.xml

```
<import resource="ws-applicationContext.xml"/>
```

soap-servlet.xml

```
<import resource="soap-applicationContext.xml"/>
```

Bot these applicationContext import a common file

Contents of soap-applicationContext.xml

```
<import resource="my-common-applicationContext.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.myproject1"/>
```

Contents of ws-applicationContext.xml

```
<import resource="my-common-applicationContext.xml"/>

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz.myproject2"/>
```

my-common-applicationContext.xml  has common packages which are needed by both like integration,data etc.

At start of application , since my-common-applicationContext.xml is included in both the application context, it gets loaded twice. This leads to DataConfigurations being loaded twice.

What is the best way to solve this problem also ensuring both the context have access to relevant beans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the right way to do it .
All common files go in common but are loaded with ContextLoaderListener. This ensures all classes are available.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:my-common-applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```